# Why react function component is behaving strangely?

Tags: reactjs

For example, I have a state and it can be changed by clicking on the buttons. I also have a log to track the rendering and rerendering of the component. When I click on the button and change the state, the log is triggered and everything is fine. But when I click 2 times on the same value, the log fires again. Clicking 3 times does nothing. Please explain what could be the reason

```
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);
  console.log("render");
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{state}</h3>
      <button onClick={() => {setState(1)}}>1</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setState(2)}}>2</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

React rerenders a component if the state is changing, but in your example, when you click on a button again, the value of state does not change, because you want to change value of 2 to 2, so react does not rerender the component.

Comment: Ok, why then the render log is triggered 2 times? Once when changing the state and the second time just when clicking?

Comment: @Danko you mean why 2 `render` is logged on each click?

Comment: I mean no, render worked 2 times for 2 different clicks on the same button,  the state changed once, so there should be 1 render, I thought so

Comment: @Danko I don't think one of logs is because of clicking on the button. because clicking on the button itself does not change the state. I even tried class component, and there, `render` logged 2 times too. I think that's how changing states are implemented in React and both of the renders is related to state changing. Even when I changed state in `useEffect` with `setTimeout`, it logged two times.